# What is the alchemical laboratory required to heal a simulacrum?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, simulacrum

The [simulacrum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum) spell says:

> If the simulacrum is damaged, you can repair it in an alchemical laboratory, using rare herbs and minerals worth 100 gp per hit point it regains.

What else is needed besides the rare herbs and minerals?

The term "alchemical laboratory" implies a room filled with...stuff, but the spell doesn't say what that stuff is.  Clearly the GM will need to interpret, but is there any other guidance that might inform that interpretation?

Possibly relevant, previous versions of the spell were worded differently.  For instance, the [AD&D 2e version of simulacrum](https://adnd2e.fandom.com/wiki/Simulacrum) said:

> Damage to the simulacrum can be repaired by a complex process requiring at least one day, 100 gp per hit point, and a fully equipped laboratory.

Maybe that means the intent is that the current version required a "fully equipped" laboratory, or maybe it means the opposite.

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for here?  You acknowledge that it'll be up to the DM. Are you hoping for an idea of how many gold it takes to outfit a bare room as an alchemical lab?  A list of lab equipment with prices for each piece?  I can't tell what sort of answer you hope to get or how it will be applied.

Comment: It's likely not a question that can successfuly be asked around here, to get suggestions what ar reasonable lab would look like or cost, as there is no official guidance and you cannot ask for an opinion. I think its a pity, because for me, hearing how others handle it does have some value, but this is likely something you'd need to go to a forum or the chat here for.

Comment: @Jack: put some stuff for you into the [general chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat), maybe its useful

Comment: I actually got the answer I was looking for, more or less.  I certainly couldn't find any further guidance, and if rpg.se doesn't pop up with some obscure table or obnoxious unofficial guidance, that gives me a platform from whoch to discuss it with the GM.  Lol, the things i come up with the answers are usually either "sure", "hard no", or "you want to do what? what does rpg.se say", and then we figure out the answer from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There's no guidance, ask your DM.

If you search the rules for [alchemical laboratory](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.dndbeyond.com%2Fsources%2F%20%22alchemical%20laboratory%22) you'll find the only reference to it is in the text of Simulacrum.

However there are some examples of [alchemical laboratories in adventures that may serve as inspiration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=alchemical%20laboratory).

Answer (score 6):

#### Ask your DM if a particular laboratory is sufficient.

“Alchemical laboratory” is not a game term with a game-specific definition. “Alchemical laboratory” is as specific as the author chose to be, leaving the interpretation of that up to the DM. There is no further guidance given about what constitutes an alchemical laboratory for the purposes of *simulacrum*.

The times I’ve had players use the spell, I’ve been a bit more strict than just “a room with alchemy equipment”. I’ve required them to search out institutes of research or industry that have labs dedicated to alchemical pursuits and make use of those, usually requiring appointments and short term rental contracts. To me, I *don’t* want *simulacrum* to be “I get to play my character twice in fights”, so I make it a chore to get one healed. This has led to, in my estimation, far more creative uses for the spell than just “double damage in combat”. I’ve had players use simulacra to run places of business, undertake low-risk side quests, and I even had one player whose character tried to juggle two lovers, which ultimately blew up in his face.

But I talk to my players about this before they commit to the spell. I explain that I’m going to make it a bother to get the thing healed, and how I like to encourage creative, non-combat applications of the spell. That way there is less disappointment - I don’t want a player to expect it to work one way, and find out in the moment I’m ruling it another way. And I think this is the real right answer. There really is no right or wrong ruling here, the DM and players should work together to come up with a solution that works so that the player feels like their choice was worth it and the spell doesn’t present too many challenges for the DM.